# Programmatically toggle class on ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to programmatically toggle the class on a single ng-repeat element, but my code appears to set it to all of the elements, and there is no way to reset it. How can I fix this?

**instant.html**

```
<div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="service in businessServiceList | filter:services">
  {{service.title}}
  <div class="buttons" style="padding: 0px">
    <button class="button {{buttonStyle}}" ng-click="changeButtonStyle()">
      <i class="ion-android-done"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button button-stable">
      <i class="ion-android-more-horizontal"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('BookCtrl', function($scope, ServicesData, $stateParams) {
  $scope.businessServiceList = ServicesData.getBusinessServiceList ($stateParams.business);
  $scope.buttonStyle="button-stable";
  $scope.changeButtonStyle = function(){
    $scope.buttonStyle="button-positive";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ng-class, you must use!

```
<div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="service in businessServiceList | filter:services">
  {{service.title}}
  <div class="buttons" style="padding: 0px">
    <button class="button" 
        ng-class="{ 'button-positive': isButtonClicked }" ng-click="isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked">
      <i class="ion-android-done"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button button-stable">
      <i class="ion-android-more-horizontal"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, in the ng-class attribute you can just put all your classes that should be toggled by certain conditions.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much!